# Bulkify this trigger on Contact?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, governorlimits

```
trigger ContactID on Contact (before insert, before update, after update, after delete)
{
    //
    // list of contacts to modify
    Set<Contact> conSet = new Set<Contact>();
    Set<Id> keepCon = new Set<Id>();
    List<Contact> updCon = new List<Contact>();
    Set<String> extIds = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();

    // handle inserts - add external id
    if(trigger.isInsert)
    {
        for(Contact c:trigger.new)
        {
            if(c.Email != null)
            {
                conSet.add(c);
                emails.add(c.Email);
            }
        }
        for(Contact con: [SELECT Id, ExternalId__c FROM Contact WHERE ExternalId__c != null AND Email IN: emails])
        {
            extIds.add(con.ExternalId__c);
        }

        for(Contact ins:conSet)
        {
            Integer i = 0;
            while(ins.ExternalId__c == null)
            {
                if(extIds.contains(ins.Email + '(' + i + ')'))
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    ins.ExternalId__c = ins.Email + '(' + i + ')';
                }
            }
            extIds.add(ins.ExternalId__c);
        }
        extIds.clear();
        emails.clear();
    }

    else if(trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        for(Contact c:trigger.new)
        {
            if(c.ExternalId__c == null && c.Email != null)
            {
                conSet.add(c);
                emails.add(c.Email);
            }
            else if((trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Email != trigger.newMap.get(c.Id).Email) && c.Email != null)
            {
                conSet.add(c);
                c.ExternalId__c = null;
                emails.add(c.Email);
            }
        }

        for(Contact con: [SELECT Id, ExternalId__c FROM Contact WHERE ExternalId__c != null AND Email IN: emails])
        {
            extIds.add(con.ExternalId__c);
        }

        for(Contact upd:conSet)
        {
            Integer i = 0;
            while(upd.ExternalId__c == null)
            {
                if(extIds.contains(upd.Email + '(' + i + ')'))
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    upd.ExternalId__c = upd.Email + '(' + i + ')';
                }
            }
            extIds.add(upd.ExternalId__c);
        }
        extIds.clear();
        emails.clear();
    }

    else if(trigger.isDelete)
    {
        for(Contact c:trigger.old)
        {
            if(c.MasterRecordId != null)
            {
                keepCon.add(c.MasterRecordId);
            }
        }

        for(Contact c: [SELECT Id, ExternalId__c FROM Contact WHERE Id IN: keepCon AND Email != null])
        {
            conSet.add(c);
            c.ExternalId__c = null;
        }

        for(Contact kept:conSet)
        {
            Integer i=0;
            while(kept.ExternalId__c == null)
            {
                if(extIds.contains(kept.Email + '(' + i + ')'))
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    kept.ExternalId__c = kept.Email + '(' + i + ')';
                }
            }
            extIds.add(kept.ExternalId__c);
        }
        extIds.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your whole trigger please. We cannot tell what gov limit you are hitting. SOQL within a loop? Etc.

Comment: The line you included is fine. We need more information to help you.

Comment: paste code in pastebin kinda sites n upload the code

Comment: @YsrShk Dont paste code on an outside site, which may go down or remove the pasted content at some point in the future. [Edit] the question to include code.

Comment: @battery.cord yeah right.

Comment: Not sure if this is good enough but the last line of code is the line that errors.  Can I link from  Notepad++?

Comment: You won't be able to upload a file into your post, and frankly, you shouldn't. If your trigger won't fit into the space you have to ask your question, you may already have the answer on why your trigger is hitting limits.

Comment: Thanks, @battery.cord.  My trigger is not horribly long, only a few more than 76 lines.  I've got 2 SOQL queries that I'd like to remove the SOQL from and wondering if there is a simple way to do that.

Comment: **[Edit] your question to include your entire trigger.**

Comment: You must have other triggers on `Contact` and this is just the straw that breaks the camel's back. There's nothing to bulkify here.

Comment: Ugh, I do.  Darn it, thanks for looking into it, all!  Thanks, Adrian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger you have posted is properly bulkified, and will not cause you to overrun your governor limits except in a system with other triggers on `Contact`. You will have to look at those other triggers to identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid putting code in your Trigger.  Instead it's considered best practice to create a "handler" class that contains the methods you want to run during your trigger and you call those methods from your trigger.  This can help reduce duplicate code, which your trigger has some.

This bit of code here is duplicated in your insert, update, and delete triggers.

```
for(Contact con: [SELECT Id, ExternalId__c FROM Contact WHERE ExternalId__c != null AND Email IN: emails])
{
    extIds.add(con.ExternalId__c);
}

for(Contact upd:conSet)
{
    Integer i = 0;
    while(upd.ExternalId__c == null)
    {
        if(extIds.contains(upd.Email + '(' + i + ')'))
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            upd.ExternalId__c = upd.Email + '(' + i + ')';
        }
    }
    extIds.add(upd.ExternalId__c);
}
```

It would be a good idea to extract this code out into another class as a method.  This way it would only be written once, you could call it from all three triggers, and refactoring/debugging will be easier with only one method that does the work.

---

You should really read the documentation on [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm) as your code demonstrates a lack of understanding of how they work.

In your Trigger declaration you specify `before insert,` **before update, after update**`, after delete`

Your second `else if` statement `else if(trigger.isUpdate)` doesn't check for `trigger.isBefore` or `trigger.isAfter` which means it will run for both causing duplication of the code and adding at least 1 to your SOQL query count. Except that according to the documentation on context variables

> You can use an object to change its own field values using trigger.new, but only in before triggers. In all after triggers, trigger.new is not saved, so a runtime exception is thrown.

You'll want to change the code so that it only runs on before insert to avoid the runtime error.

Finally in your last `else if(trigger.isDelete)` statement you are using `trigger.old` in your for loop which means setting the values for ExternalId in that bit of code won't work and will throw an exception if it is run.

Also based on your variables `keepCon` and `kept` it would seem you want to prevent deletion but nothing in the code does that. You could use the [`addError()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError) method to prevent deletion, but you'd have to change to before delete and use trigger.new